# ASP.NET Membership validate password

Tags: asp.net, membership

I use ASP.NET Membership to manage users on my site.
But I need to create the user accounts manually, without the help of the CreateUserWizard.
I have set textboxes for the required fields, and now I am setting up validators.

The question is: How do I make a validator that would see if the password the user enters in the textbox is valid?

I know that there is a specific format the password must have, but that can be changed, and I would like for the validator to work even if that changes. So a regular expression validator won't work (i think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a simple way. However, you can use the `Membership.CreateUser` that takes a `MembershipCreateStatus` param.

If the password is valid, the created user object will be null and the MembershipCreateStatus will be set to `InvalidPassword` (or any other creation status).

Example:

```
MembershipCreateStatus membershipCreateStatus;
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(userName, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, true, out membershipCreateStatus);

// Check if the user was created succesfully
if (newUser == null)
{
    // membershipCreateStatus contains the information why the creation was not successful
    if (membershipCreateStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword)
    {
        // The password doesn't match the requirements
    }
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to use Membership.CreateUser(username, password) within a try catch and catch the MembershipCreateUserException exception. The MembershipCreateUserException.StatusCode gives a host of status code that you can use to determine why the create user failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the regex of a regular expression validator.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    passwordValidator.ValidationExpression = someConfiguration.GetPasswordValidationExpression();
}
```

Comment: But the regex expression is not stored by me anywhere.
At the moment, I use the default password restrictions (>6 chars, at least one number, and at least one special char).
If I go to my web.config and add minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0" to my membership provider, that changes the password restrictions, and I don't use any regular expression.

I am looking for something like Membership.IsThisPasswordValid(password), but that doesn't seem to exist. A method like that would validate the password according to whatever is in the web.config, and I could call it in a CustomValidator

Answer (score 0):

What's your objection to using (a variant) of the CreateUserWizard? If it's to do with needing additional fields, or the layout there are ways around that:

1. [How to: Customize the CreateUserWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342.aspx) - Check out the section on "To customize the CreateUserWizard steps".
2. [ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adaptors](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/) (these are going to be built into ASP.NET 4.0)

But even the default CreateUserWizard doesn't do client side password validation, I guess for this very reason :(